# Dolbeault cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Let $X=S^{2n-1} \times S^1$. I have to compute $H^{(1,0)}_{\bar{\partial}} (X)$  and

$H^{(0,1)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)$ . I don't know how to do this but if we use Kunnet formula we

have that $dim(H^{(0,1)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X))$ $+$

$dim(H^{(1,0)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X))=1$, so we

have that $H^{(1,0)}_{\bar{\partial}}(X)\simeq \mathbb{C}$

and $H^{(0,1)}_{\bar{\partial}} (X)\simeq 0$

or vice versa. I find that $X \simeq (\mathbb{C}^{n}-\{0\})/\mathbb{Z} $ via the

action $d:(z_1, \cdots, z_n) \mapsto(\lambda^dz_1, \cdots, \lambda^dz_n)$ with $n>1$,

$\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and $|\lambda|>1$. Futhermore I read that

$H=\bar{\partial}log(|z_1|^2+ \cdots +|z_n|^2)$ represents a non trivial class. But how can

I prove that $H$ is a closed but non exact form?

Answer (score 8):

You seem to have some basic misunderstandings here.

For non-Kähler manifolds, like the Hopf manifold that you consider, the Dolbeault cohomology is not in general topological, and it depends a lot on the complex structure that you have. Note that there are many different (i.e. not biholomorphic) complex structure on the smooth manifold $S^{2n-1}\times S^1$.

Also, the Künneth formula as you stated it is wrong, and you cannot just use topology to compute the Hodge numbers. But note that the [Frölicher spectral sequence](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073%2Fpnas.41.9.641) in particular implies that $h^{1,0}(X)+h^{0,1}(X)\geq b_1(X)$ for any compact complex manifold $X$.

Having said this, let's suppose that you look at the Hopf manifold $X$ that you define as your explicit $\mathbb{Z}$ quotient (this defines the complex structure uniquely, independent of the value of your parameter $\lambda$). Then its Hodge numbers were calculated a long time ago (first by A.Borel, I believe, again using spectral sequences for the more general class of Calabi-Eckmann manifolds). You can find the result conveniently packaged in [this paper of Höfer](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.kjm/1250519346), see page 232. In particular, we have $h^{0,1}(X)=1, h^{1,0}(X)=0$ for this particular Hopf manifold (here I am assuming $n\geq 2$).

The last question that you ask is a nice exercise for you!

Comment: @YangMills But I have to find a method to show that $H$ is an exact but not closed form... 